# Unity 3d Light Projector Not Working in 0 Intensity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, light, projector

I am making a complete dark scene in my game, which has 0 directional light intensity and very dark ambient environment color. The problem is that Unity Light Projector shows nothing or barely visible light if there is 0 light intensity and dark ambient environment color but works fine if I increases the Directional Light Intensity or brightened the ambient environment color. Is there any shader which could solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: What material/shader does your projector use?

Comment: Unity own Projector/Light material.